# Office 365 app inside iframe?

Tags: asp.net, redirect, iframe, asp.net-web-api, window

OK, guys need some advice with runing ASP.Net app inside iframe.

I have a CMS and ASP.Net app which talks to Office 365.

Because I couldn't integrate my app into CMS (authentication issue) I am calling my office app using [jQuery Window
Plugin](http://fstoke.me/jquery/window/) which has two advantages:

1. I styled the window to look as though its part of the CMS
2. It has onClose event which I was able to use as a trigger that I need to update UI

Everything works great. Only issue is when user goes to sign in. Because Office API call a remote service it redirects my office app to the authentication page. And this breaks the iframe. Leaving user to stare at a blank dialog window till they get bored.

Prior to discovering that plugin I used normal javascript `window.open()` which opened up a new `browser` window for me where everything works fine. But the biggest problem for me is that inside CMS context I can't tell when/if user has finished using my office app. Therefore I have no hooks I can rely on to trigger UI update leaving user to just refresh the page.

Is there anything I can do to get around my problem (apart from integrating my office app with CMS)?

**ps:**
My office is basically sending HTTP messages across the web to CMS in order to do what needs to be done.

**pss:**
My office app in turn uses latest Office 365 API to talk to its services.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies guys. Just confirmed that Office 365 is configure not to display inside iframes.

That pretty much leaves only two options:

1. running a separate `browser` window
2. tighter integration with CMS (ideal)

Comment: Almost 3 years ago, I'm wondering if this has changed or if there's any new workaround.

Comment: I doubt anything changed with regards to iframe because Microsoft considers this a security risk. For the last three years, I had it as a stand-alone app. But currently looking at tighter integration with CMS as there have been many changes. I should be able to replace the app with simple https requests provided I have a valid user token.