# Multifactor authentication to 365 within a sideloading Office App?

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-2013, office365api, office-js

I know this is similar to

[Office 365 app inside iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29283544/office-365-app-inside-iframe)

But that has no answers, and I have a marginally different question.

I have a problem using Multifactor authentication to 365 SharePoint sites within a side-loading app in Word. (a side-loading app in SharePoint is not an option as our tenant annoyingly has aps build disabled.)

Word Side-load does not allow frames at all so you are limited to just simple webpages.

So I am looking at this code to see if it works.

Try a better link!

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-load-in-and-animate-content-with-jquery

The suggestion is jquery could remove the need for iframes?

Are there any experts here who have done multifactor authentication using jquery to manipulate your page?

Answer (score 1):

Authentication within add-ins can be difficult, but the problems are mostly mitigated by using pop-ups during the authentication process.

Here is the official documentation on this type of scenario.
Use the OAuth authorization framework in an Office Add-in - https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/mt629180.aspx

These two samples might be helpful, depending in the server-side technology you use.

- https://github.com/officeDev/Office-Add-in-Nodejs-ServerAuth
- https://github.com/dougperkes/Office-Add-in-AspNetMvc-ServerAuth

There is a new framework called DisplayDialog that can simplify the setup required here. See this branch for samples:
https://github.com/dougperkes/Office-Add-in-AspNetMvc-ServerAuth/tree/Office2016DisplayDialog